# Android + Change image state on button widget

Tags: android, imagebutton

Ok I am having a LOT of trouble finding an answer for this question. So either I'm asking it wrong or going about it the completely wrong way. Either way I could use some help. So what I'm trying to do is implement dynamic image cycling on a button widget based on state.

What I mean by this is

```
On Mouse Down {
  Change to this image
}

On Click {
 Button functionality
}

On Mouse Up {
 Change back to original
}
```

I've seen a LOT of tutorials that place this under the click event but this isn't really what I want. I don't just simply want to change the color of the button when the button is pressed I want it to flash with the alternate image quickly and then Change back to the Original image placed on the button. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

From the Link:

EXAMPLE:
XML file saved at res/drawable/button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout XML applies the state list drawable to a Button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot you're a real lifesaver. I WAS trying to do this completely wrong. I was trying to use the generated Java file not xml files. This works perfectly though and results in less code :)